# Create an object from the current class in a static method - PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance

I have some problems with my class Model and other classes so I made this simple example to explain my problem :

```
class person{

  public static $a = "welcome";

  public function __construct(){
                               }

  public static function getobject()
  {
      $v = new person();
      return $v;
  }

}

class student extends person{

  public static $b = "World";

}

$st = student:getobject();//this will return person object but I want student object

echo $st->$b; // There is an error here because the object is not student
```

So I want to know what to write instead `$v = new person();` to get the object of the last inherited class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)'s `static` keyword.

```
public static function getobject()
{
    $v = new static();
    return $v;
}
```

So, with `student::getobject()` you get an instance of `student`.

To retrieve the static (but why?) `$b` propriety, you can do `$st::$b`, or simply `student::$b`.